# Can't use Tensorflow.js predict() function

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I've trained my own graph model. And I want to use it on browser. Here is my code:

```
async function predict() {
        const model = await tf.loadGraphModel('./model/model.json');
        let img = document.getElementById('test');
        var example = tf.browser.fromPixels(img);
        example = example.expandDims(0);
        const output = await model.predict(example).data();
        console.log(output);
    }
```

When I run this, it gives this error on console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: This execution contains the node 'SecondStagePostprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/Exit_4', which has the dynamic op 'Exit'. Please use model.executeAsync() instead. Alternatively, to avoid the dynamic ops, specify the inputs [SecondStagePostprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/TensorArrayStack_2/TensorArrayGatherV3]
    at t.compile (tfjs:2)
    at t.execute (tfjs:2)
    at t.execute (tfjs:2)
    at predict ((index):85)
    at /websites/optik2/async http://localhost/websites/optik2/:96
```

I need `predict()` function, `executeAsync()` is not good as it is.

**EDIT**

Ok, I'm using as `executeAsync` now as [@Jason Mayes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5627842/jason-mayes) says. But it's returning some values like that:

```
t {kept: false, isDisposedInternal: false, shape: Array(3), dtype: "float32", size: 1200, …}
rank: 3
isDisposed: false
kept: false
isDisposedInternal: false
shape: (3) [1, 300, 4]
dtype: "float32"
size: 1200
strides: (2) [1200, 4]
dataId: {}
id: 2198
rankType: "3"
scopeId: 3545
__proto__: Object
```

How can I get the bounding box of this?

Comment: What is wrong with executeAsync() ?

Comment: Ok, I'm using it now. And do you know how can I get bounding box from executeAsync. It's my own model

Comment: What is returned currently? As it is async you need to wait for it to complete before you will populate output. Updated answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What is the length of the output from `const output = await model.executeAsync(data)`?

You should look for these shapes in the `output`;

```
output[X] = detection_boxes   // shape: [1, x, 4]  x: number of bounding boxes
output[Y] = detection_scores  // shape: [1, x]     x: number of scores
output[Z] = detection_classes // shape: [1, x]     x: number of classes
```

Then you can fetch the predictions through the following;

```
const boxes = output[0].dataSync()
const scores = output[1].arraySync()
const classes = output[2].dataSync()
```

You can then construct a prediction object with all the predicted bounding boxes by doing this;

```
buildDetectedObjects(scores, threshold, imageWidth, imageHeight, boxes, classes, classesDir) {
    const detectionObjects = []
    scores.forEach((score, i) => {
      if (score > threshold) {
        const bbox = [];
        const minY = boxes[i * 4] * imageHeight;
        const minX = boxes[i * 4 + 1] * imageWidth;
        const maxY = boxes[i * 4 + 2] * imageHeight;
        const maxX = boxes[i * 4 + 3] * imageWidth;
        bbox[0] = minX;
        bbox[1] = minY;
        bbox[2] = maxX - minX;
        bbox[3] = maxY - minY;

        detectionObjects.push({
          class: classes[i],
          label: classesDir[classes[i]].name,
          score: score.toFixed(4),
          bbox: bbox
        })
      }
    })

    return detectionObjects
  }
```

`classesDir` being a dictionary with the classes from the training;

```
let classesDir = {
    1: {
        name: 'Class name 1',
        id: 1,
    },
    2: {
        name: 'Class name 2',
        id: 2,
    }
}
```

The prediction object will then be an array with objects;

```
[{
  bbox:[x,y,width,height],
  class: X,
  label: class name,
  score: 0.XYZ
},
{
  bbox:[x,y,width,height],
  class: X,
  label: class name,
  score: 0.XYZ
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try model.executeAsync() instead of predict.

As it is async you should use:

const output = await model.executeAsync(data);

Answer (score 2):

You are using console.log to display a tensor.

```
console.log(tensor)
```

Instead you would need to use the `print` method of the tensor to see its output.

```
tensor.print()
```

After getting the tensor from the backend, then `console.log` can be used to display the output as a plain js array

```
data = await tensor.data()
console.log(data) // plain js array
```

Comment: Thanks for you your reply. tensor.data() or tensor.dataSync(), only returns Float32Array. How can I get the bounding boxes?

Comment: If you use `data` or `dataSync` you will have an array that contains all the data. But if you want the array to keep the same shape as the tensor, you can rather use `array` or `arraySync`

Comment: What about bounding box? How can I interpret the result?

Comment: Looking at the shape `[1, 300, 4]` you have 300 bounding boxes or detections in the image.

Comment: How can I access those?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It is the output of `output.dataSync()` or `output.arraySync()`

Comment: Sorry for my poor description. I mean, I want to get all possible detections, their bounding boxes and their scores.

Comment: @sundowatch, did you resolved your issue. I am facing same issue and struggling a lot for solving it. Can you help me on it. Thanks